How to build truly "folder agnostic" react apps using yarn and react-dom-router?
I need to build a small react application (I'm using yarn and react-dom-router) to be truly "folder agnostic". That means that I don't know the folder of the web server where that app will be deployed.
It could be
/foo/
/bar/
/foo/bar/
/whatever/foo/bar/

So I followed some internet wisdom and added to package.json
"homepage": "./"

And I also changed this in vite.config.ts
base: "./"

But now I'm not sure on how to set the router. I tried several different options for the initial path, but none of them work:
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { HomeView } from "./views/home";
import { SceneryView } from "./views/scenery";
import { NotFoundView } from "./views/not-found";
import { DefaultLayout } from "./layouts/default-layout";
import { PatientView } from "./views/patient";
import { PatientEndView } from "./views/patient-end";
import { CompletedView } from "./views/completed";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/", // I think the problem is there
    element: <DefaultLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <HomeView />,
      },
      {
        path: "decision-pathways/scenery/:id",
        element: <SceneryView />,
      },
      {
        path: "decision-pathways/patient/:sceneryId/:patientId",
        element: <PatientView />,
      },
      {
        path: "decision-pathways/patient/end/:sceneryId/:patientId",
        element: <PatientEndView />,
      },
      {
        path: "decision-pathways/completed",
        element: <CompletedView />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    element: <NotFoundView />,
  },
]);

export default router;

For the "main" path I tried:
.
./
/

But none of them worked, I always get the not found page. Anyone tackled the same problem?

A homepage: "." value in your package.json file is fine, but from what I understand Vite needs to know what directory the built artifact will be deployed/served from, and then by extension the router does as well, via the basename prop. I'm not sure it's possible to create a single built artifact that is simply "drop anywhere you like". Vite needs to know where and how to link assets, etc, and the router needs to know where it's deployed to correctly match the URL to routes it manages and navigates around to in-app if it isn't just the root "/" directory.

A HashRouter might get you close to what you need, it doesn't need a basename, it just works wherever it is deployed/served from. This would leave only the Vite configuration to mess with.

@DrewReese thank you, the HashRouter is the correct way! Will post a self-answer in a few hours.

My problem was that I was stubbornly trying to implement createBrowserRouter that is essentially not compatible with my scenario.
Thanks to the comment by @DrewReese I switched to createHashRouter
import { createHashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { HomeView } from "./views/home";
import { SceneryView } from "./views/scenery";
import { NotFoundView } from "./views/not-found";
import { DefaultLayout } from "./layouts/default-layout";
import { PatientView } from "./views/patient";
import { PatientEndView } from "./views/patient-end";
import { CompletedView } from "./views/completed";

const router = createHashRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <DefaultLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <HomeView />,
      },
      {
        path: "decision-pathways/scenery/:id",
        element: <SceneryView />,
      },
      {
        path: "decision-pathways/patient/:sceneryId/:patientId",
        element: <PatientView />,
      },
      {
        path: "decision-pathways/patient/end/:sceneryId/:patientId",
        element: <PatientEndView />,
      },
      {
        path: "decision-pathways/completed",
        element: <CompletedView />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    element: <NotFoundView />,
  },
]);

export default router;

What's the difference? Basically createHashRouter add an hashtag before react "internal" route. In this way the web server ignores whatever is after that hashtag and resolves always to the same file, in this case my index.html.
For the resources all that is needed to change the paths to relative ones is this line in vite.config.js:
base: "./"

